# Join 3 table is giving an error

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables.
**tenant**
tenant_id : int
category_id : int

**category**
category_id : int
category_name : varchar(50)

**history**
tenant_id : int
bulan_tahun : varchar(8)
counter : int

i want to join all of this table using this code:

```
SELECT a.tenant_id, a.category_name 
FROM (
    (tenant INNER JOIN category ON tenant.category_id = category.category_id) AS a 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT tenant_id, counter FROM history WHERE 
            bulan_tahun = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m_%Y')
    ) AS b 
    on a.tenant_id = b.tenant_id
)
```

but this code produce an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a INNER JOIN ( SELECT tenant_id, counter FROM history WHERE bulan_tahun ' at line 3
```

if i separate the sub select, it works perfectly
for the first select:

```
SELECT tenant_id, category_name 
FROM 
(tenant INNER JOIN category ON tenant.category_id = category.category_id)
```

and the second select:

```
SELECT tenant_id, counter FROM history WHERE 
bulan_tahun = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m_%Y')
```

but if i join this together, the error occured

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies here..

```
(tenant INNER JOIN category ON tenant.category_id = category.category_id)
```

Try restructuring your entire query like this

```
SELECT a.tenant_id, c.category_name 
FROM 
    tenant t 
INNER JOIN 
    category c 
    ON ( t.category_id = c.category_id )
INNER JOIN 
        history h
    ON ( t.tenant_id = h.tenant_id )        
WHERE 
h.bulan_tahun = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m_%Y')
```

Comment: oh yes, this can be work. so basically i don't have to create sub select. thanks...